# Error in a for loop with multiplication of matrices

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

The following code fails on the `else` statements with the following error:

> File "C:\Users\feder\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py", line 195, in __getitem__
>       out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
>
> IndexError: index 117 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

```
for i in range(0, int(N / 2)):
    if i == 0:
        x[:, 0] = C * xvec_tra
        print(x[:, 0])
    else:
        x[:, i] = C * x[:, i-1] # C is matrix 4x4 and xvec_tra is a matrix 4x1
        print(x[:, i])
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What are `x`, `xvec_tra`, `N`, `C`? Without knowing these variables and their dimensions, it's difficult to help you out.

Comment: xvec_tra=transpose(np.matrix([0, atan(3.2*pi/180), 0, 0]))
N=238 (it is a number)
C=matrix([[-1.49882566e+00, -1.60277674e+02,  1.13450758e-01,
          3.64528630e+01],
        [ 3.91942189e-03, -2.39476217e-01, -1.05843520e-03,
         -2.26635057e-01],
        [ 1.13450758e-01,  3.64528630e+01, -1.49882566e+00,
         -1.60277674e+02],
        [-1.05843520e-03, -2.26635057e-01,  3.91942189e-03,
         -2.39476217e-01]])
And x will be the result of the for loop, it  should to be a matrix 4x119.